# How to do control statement for salary? (Python)

Tags: python

> Write a program that displays a salary schedule, in tabular format,
>   for teachers in a school district. The inputs are the starting salary,
>   the percentage increase, and the number of years in the schedule. Each
>   row in the schedule should contain the year number and the salary for
>   that year. The starting amount is $30,000, increases by 2% over the
>   course of 10 years.

So far, I have this:

```
startSalary = int(input("Enter start salary: "))

percentIncrease = (float(input("Enter percent increase: "))/ 100)

numberYears = list(range(1,(int(input("Enter number of years in the schedule: ")) +1 )))


def calculateSalary(startSalary, percentIncrease, numberYears):
  for year in numberYears:

    salaryIncrease = startSalary * percentIncrease
    newSalary = startSalary + salaryIncrease
    startSalary = newSalary
    print(year, newSalary)

calculateSalary(startSalary, percentIncrease, numberYears)
```

This works fine when I run the code, but for my starting year it runs as 30,600 and I need it to start at 30,000 (hence why it is the starting salary).

Comment: Is it a homework?

Comment: Yes. I do not know how to begin the first year to show up as the starting salary (30,000) instead of 30,600.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it still starts at 30,600.

Comment: `print` the salary before adding the increase.

Comment: if numberYears is 10, will you display 11 salaries or 10 salaries? If 11, print the starting salary before the for loop. if 10, refer to huck_cussier

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you haven't solved it already.

```
startSalary = int(input(" enter beginning salary: "))
percentIncrease = (float(input(" enter percentage increase: ")) / 100)
numberYears = list(range(1,(int(input(" enter number of years in schedule: "))+1)))


def calculateSalary(startSalary, percentIncrease, numberYears):    
    for year in numberYears:
        salaryIncrease = startSalary * percentIncrease
        newSalary = startSalary + salaryIncrease
        print("{} {:0.2f}".format(year, startSalary))
        startSalary = newSalary

calculateSalary(startSalary, percentIncrease, numberYears)
```

Comment: Yea, im sorry i don't know how to use this website yet.

Comment: I understand. Was new here myself once. Its worth the effort to get it right. People like to downvote badly formatted code, and there is no penalty for fiddling with your answer until you get it right. Also its usually a good idea to write a short paragraph explaining how you solved the OP's problem.  Quality gets rewarded here ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
from tabulate import tabulate
a = ['year', 'salary']
b = [[i+1, 30000*(1.02**i)] for i in range(10)]

print(tabulate(b, a))

   year    salary
  ------  --------
     1   30000
     2   30600
     3   31212
     4   31836.2
     5   32473
     6   33122.4
     7   33784.9
     8   34460.6
     9   35149.8
    10   35852.8
```